# Best way to prevent logger to not log when a specific api is called

Tags: nestjs

New to NestJS world here. 
I'm developing a new service in NestJS that will run on kubernetes. On K8s i have healtcheck which calls and endpoint every second, and this pollutes my logs. 
 I was thinking to create a custom decorator called for example @SkipLog which adds a parameter to req object and then in the logger check if this parameter exists and skip the log.

As I'm not expert of NestJS world could this approach work? Or do you have any suggestion on a better way ?
Thanks

Comment: If I were you, I would filter my logs rather than try to write a SkipLog decorator

Comment: How is the healthcheck implemented? Are you using this https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/terminus#healthchecks-terminus? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, i've used terminus to do the healtcheck